# How to load LIBS based on User name?

Tags: qt, environment-variables, qmake

I want to run my program in two different machines and they have two different user names and different library paths. I want to define LIBS , INCLUDEPATH and DEPENDPATH  based on user name detected from the environment variable in my Qt .pro file. Is there a way to achieve it? 
I am using Scientific Linux 6.5 and Qt 5.3.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the lib files having the same name in two path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$$(USER)` to get the user env var in qmake. All thats left is to do is to decide which to use based on that value.

Simple example:

```
CURRENT_USER = $$(USER)
message("The current user is: $$CURRENT_USER")

equals(CURRENT_USER, "user1") {
    LIBS += -L/first/path/lib -lstuff
    INCLUDEPATH += /first/path/include
} else:equals(CURRENT_USER, "user2") {
    LIBS += -L/second/path/lib -lstuff
    INCLUDEPATH += /second/path/include
} //...
```

Note: If, for example, the library was located in `~/libs/mylib` for each user, you can also do something like this:

```
LIBS += -L$$(HOME)/libs/mylib/lib -lstuff
INCLUDEPATH += $$(HOME)/libs/mylib/include
```